# Django use a variable within a template tag

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, django-templates

I am using the static template tag in my Django template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

But instead of `"my_app/myexample.jpg"`, I need to use a file name that is a property of my model object (i.e. `{{ SampleModel.0.propertyValue }}`, which I am passing as context to this template. But how do I include `{{ ... }}` within the static template tag? It throws an error.

Any way out?

Comment: If you include a dynamic value, should that asset be _static_? You may have perfectly good reasons to do so, but it may hint poor application design aswell

Comment: @Mischback : I have images with file names that can be generated by the properties of the model objects. Instead of this, how do I approach the problem then..

Comment: Personally I would code my own template tag for this use-case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use use a variable in the static template tag. Note that you don't need the `{{` or `}}`

```
{% static SampleModel.0.propertyValue %}
```

Comment: if the path is "images/{{ SampleModel.0.propertyValue }}.png" then?

Comment: Then you can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter: `{% static "images"|add:SampleModel.0.propertyValue|add:".png" %}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any variable from your context in Django tags (custom tags may need some adjustments to work with it). In your case, this works fine:

```
{% static SampleModel.0.propertyValue %}
```

This usages also work:

```
{% with my_computed_var=SampleModel.0.propertyValue %}
    {% static my_computed_var %} 
{% endwith %}

{% static some_var|customFilter %}
```

See [the documentation about custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) for more information, it is also relevant for Django defaults tags.