# How to access @property variable in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, wagtail

I have a dropdown choice that an editor in Wagtail can use to choose an icon. Their choice will be mapped to a preset list of static assets.

I'm trying to use a calculated attribute to get the path to the icon. I then want to use that within my template.

Something is wrong. The template is perfectly happy with `{{ card.text }}` but doesn't work with {{ card.svg_url }}. It is not erroring, returning, or apparently even being called.

How can I debug or fix this?

panel template:

```html
{% for card in card_list %}
<div>
    {{ card.svg_url }} <!-- Neither of the svg_urls appear -->
    <img class="card__icon" src="{% static card.svg_url %}">
    <p>{{ card.text }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```py
class CardBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    icon = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[
        ('calendar', 'Calendar'),
        ('flag', 'Flag'),
    ])
    text = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=100)

    @property
    def svg_url(self):
        print("calling svg_url...") # testing
        svg_map = {
            'calendar': 'img/calendar.svg',
            'flag': 'img/flag.svg',
        }

        return svg_map[self.icon]


class PanelBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    heading = block.CharBlock()
    card_list = blocks.ListBlock(
        CardBlock(),
    )

    class Meta:
        template = "website/blocks/panel.html"
```

Comment: Can you try adding a print statement inside the `svg_url` property and test whether it gets called?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I added a print statement (edited code above) and I am not getting any prints in the command prompt :/

Comment: Does removing @property in front the `svg_url` property print the statement?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I removed it and still nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I have tried sticking `{{ card.svg_url }}` into the template to spit out raw text, but that's not working either. I think something about the way I'm referencing the variable must be incorrect, but I don't get any template errors.

Comment: But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31756876/12467282), your method looks fine. Did you pass `card` into your context? Entry-level, but I just want to be sure

Comment: I am using a wagtail block, so I didn't add anything to context, but I am able to access non-@property variables (my example is simplified) --- I will adjust the code to reflect this more accurately.

see updated code for `card.text` which works as expected

Comment: @gasman Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it out. I think that will answer my question.